# Django calling function of one to one relation

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

I have following two classes:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'new contact'
        # this should return __str__ of Information if both 
        # first_name and last_name exists

class Information(models.Model):
    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, related_name='information')
    first_name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
        ])
```

One to one relation between `Contact` and `Information` is created automatically when `Contact` is created

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact)
def create_one_to_ones(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Information.objects.create(contact=instance)
```

My problem is that I would like to call **str** method of `Information` when **str** of `Contact` is called. If `Information` has both `first_name` and `last_name` then those should be shown but if not then just return default `'new contact'` string.

How I can call **str** method of that other class? Related name is `information` so I tried for example `self.information.__str__()` and I got an error `DoesNotExist at /
Contact has no information.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I get your question right, but you have access to the self.information object or is it None?

If exists, have you tried `str(self.information)`? This should call the str function of your object.
So, the **str** method of the Contact Model could look like the following:

```
 #Contact Model
 def __str__(self):
        if self.information.first_name is not None and self.information.last_name is not None:
            return str(self.information)
        return 'new contact'
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Not sure why I couldn't call self.information.__str__() but with self.information everything works. I had to modify your solution little bit, I wrote it like this: if self.information.first_name and self.information.last_name:
            return str(self.information.get_name())
        return 'new contact' and then everything works. With your solution it never returns 'new contact' even though strings are empty.

Comment: Returning str(self.information) works of course as well, get_name()-function calls just __str__().